# Quarkus MutinyEmitter<T> timeout waiting for the signal

Tags: apache-kafka, timeout, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

we are using Quarkus/Smallrye reactive messaging to produce messages to the Kafka topic.
In most cases this works well.
However - from time to time - we are facing timeouts - meaning the `emitter.sendMessage(message)` does not produce either Item or Failure signal and the downstream part of the pipeline timeouts.
What is strange - messages are happily written in the Kafka topic.
We have implemented a retry wrapper over the `sendMessage` call, but the results are just duplicate messages in the target topic.
Code sample here:

```
return Uni.createFrom().deferred(() -> emitter.sendMessage(message).replaceWith(message))
                .ifNoItem().after(timeout).failWith(() -> {
                    Log.warnf("Timeout emitting %s %s to %s Kafka channel", event.getClass().getSimpleName(), event.getId(), channelName);
                    return new TimeoutException();
                })
                .onFailure(TimeoutException.class).retry().atMost(numberOfAttempts)
                .onFailure(th -> {
                    Log.errorf(th, "Error emitting %s %s to %s Kafka channel", event.getClass().getSimpleName(), event.getId(), channelName);
                    return th instanceof IllegalStateException;
                }).retry().withBackOff(timeout, timeout).atMost(numberOfAttempts);
```

Is there a way to detect what's going on behind the scenes?

Jan

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue I suggest you disable outgoing retries with `retries=0`: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/latest/kafka/writing-kafka-records/#configuration-reference